# Normalizing android accelerometer data so that x,y,z are always referencing the same orientation regardless of device's orientation

Tags: accelerometer, world-coordinates

I'm writing an Android app to gather the `x,y,z` forces from the accelerometer, and periodically transmit them back to a server.
On the server, I have a program that runs through the data to determine hard braking, fast acceleraton and hard curving.
However, my formulas only work if the android device captured the accelerometer while it was in a specific orientation. If the device's orientation is changed,
then the `x,y,z` forces are mixed up and my function fails.

Does anyone know how to standardize the `x,y,z` forces from the Android accelerometer so that `x` will always represent the force applied to east-west, y will always represent the force applied to north-south, and `z` will always represent the force applied to up-down?

I've tried various forms of converting the `x,y,z` to world coordinates, but I haven't figured out the correct formula to do so

Comment: You are probably looking for something that combines the Accels with Magnetometers.  Align the Accel and Magnetometer axis, use the Mags to determine direction wrt Magnetic North, you then know what direction the Accels are pointing.  Not saying this is easy, but have a look at this paper http://circuits.ece.ntua.gr/documents/journals/J38_A%20Single-Step_Method_for_Accelerometer_and_Magnetometer_Axes_Alignment.pdf